# how to deserialize part of the JSON object using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. and i am receiving the following json object :-

```
{  
   "operation":{  
      "name":"GET RESOURCE ACCOUNTLIST",
      "result":{  
         "status":"Success",
         "message":"Resource details with account list fetched successfully"
      },
      "Details":{  
         "RESOURCE ID":"1",
         "RESOURCE NAME":"test resource",
         "RESOURCE DESCRIPTION":"",
         "RESOURCE TYPE":"Windows",
         "DNS NAME":"172.16.20.101",
         "PASSWORD POLICY":"Strong",
         "DEPARTMENT":"",
         "LOCATION":"",
         "RESOURCE URL":"",
         "RESOURCE OWNER":"admin",
         "ACCOUNT LIST":[  
            {  
               "ISFAVPASS":"false",
               "ACCOUNT NAME":"root",
               "PASSWDID":"1",
               "IS_TICKETID_REQD_MANDATORY":"false",
               "ISREASONREQUIRED":"false",
               "AUTOLOGONLIST":[  
                  "Windows Remote Desktop",
                  "Remote Desktop"
               ],
               "PASSWORD STATUS":"****",
               "IS_TICKETID_REQD":"false",
               "ACCOUNT ID":"1",
               "AUTOLOGONSTATUS":"User is not allowed to automatically logging in to remote systems in mobile",
               "IS_TICKETID_REQD_ACW":"false"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I am using JSON.NET to do the deserilization, so I created the following  model classes (I did not include all the properties received by the JSON object since I do not really need all of them).

```
public class ResourceAccountListInfo
{
    public Operation2 operation { get; set; }
}

public class Operation2
{    
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public IList<Details2> Details { get; set; }    
}

public class Details2
{     
    [JsonProperty("RESOURCE DESCRIPTION")]
    public string RESOURCEDESCRIPTION { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("RESOURCE NAME")]
    public string RESOURCENAME { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("RESOURCE ID")]
    public string RESOURCEID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("RESOURCE TYPE")]
    public string RESOURCETYPE { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DNS NAME")]
    public string DNSNAME { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ACCOUNT LIST")]
    public IList<ACCOUNTLIST> ACCOUNTLIST { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the following error when I try to deserialize json using this statement:

```
  ResourceAccountListInfo resourceAccountListInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourceAccountListInfo>(json);
```

Error is :

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T.ViewModels.Details2]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'operation.Details.['RESOURCE ID']', line 1, position 171
```

I think the problem is that there are some properties inside my JSON object which do not have a mapping inside the model classes, could this be a reason?

Comment: Why do you have `Details` as a list anyway? It's not a list in your json, it's an object. Change your `public IList<Details2> Details { get; set; }` to `public Details2 Details { get; set; }`

Comment: @MattBurland you are 100% correct,, but this will not have any differences,, i edit my quesytion ,, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Of course it makes a difference. It's exactly what your error message is telling you, it can't convert an object from your json into a collection because it's not a collection.

Comment: so you mean i do not need to provide a map for all the json properties at the end ?

Comment: No. Any properties you don't care about, don't map them. They will be ignored. Your `Details2` class already maps what (I assume) are just the properties you care about.

Comment: Everything that does not a part of your json in c# model should be marked as [JsonIgnore]

Comment: You don't need to map all attributes of JSON to your C# object. You can use only the ones you need. What important is, you need to indicate Array or List types while deserializing.

Comment: @MattBurland my code worked well now ,, thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. FWIW, I added an answer to elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message here is actually pretty instructive:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T.ViewModels.Details2]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'operation.Details.['RESOURCE ID']', line 1, position 171

What it's telling you is that it has an object and you have asked it to deserialize it as a collection. It can't do that, because it isn't a collection to start with.

You have in your model:

```
public IList<Details2> Details { get; set; }
```

But the corresponding `details` property in your json is:

```
  "Details":{  
     "RESOURCE ID":"1",
     "RESOURCE NAME":"test resource",
     "RESOURCE DESCRIPTION":"",
     "RESOURCE TYPE":"Windows",
     "DNS NAME":"172.16.20.101",
     "PASSWORD POLICY":"Strong",
     "DEPARTMENT":"",
     "LOCATION":"",
     "RESOURCE URL":"",
     "RESOURCE OWNER":"admin",
     "ACCOUNT LIST":[  
        {  
           "ISFAVPASS":"false",
           "ACCOUNT NAME":"root",
           "PASSWDID":"1",
           "IS_TICKETID_REQD_MANDATORY":"false",
           "ISREASONREQUIRED":"false",
           "AUTOLOGONLIST":[  
              "Windows Remote Desktop",
              "Remote Desktop"
           ],
           "PASSWORD STATUS":"****",
           "IS_TICKETID_REQD":"false",
           "ACCOUNT ID":"1",
           "AUTOLOGONSTATUS":"User is not allowed to automatically logging in to remote systems in mobile",
           "IS_TICKETID_REQD_ACW":"false"
        }
     ]
  }
```

Which is an object (note the curly braces `{}`).

So all you need to do is change your `Details` property to:

```
public Details2 Details { get; set; }
```

Any properties in your json `details` that don't have a corresponding property in `Details2` will be silently ignored. So you **don't need to map every property from your json** only map the ones you actually care about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JObject` with `dynamic`:

```
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

And then populate your model the way you want, without creating the whole class hierarchy:

```
var operationName = json.operation.name;
```

Please notice: with `dynamic` your properties get created in runtime. It means that you will not have intellisense support and if you try to call method or property that doesn't exist you will get a runtime exception. So, be very careful with this approach.